# how i show manual data in a post

Tags: posts, database

Sorry for my english,
I've created a table mysql with data.
Name of my table is 'test'.
Field is: id, name, description

I would like to show them in a post page with a plugin.

For example:
if i call a url

**mysite.com/test/data1**

i would like:

- **the_ID()** to be **test.id**
- **the_title()** to be **test.name**
- **the_content()** to be **test.description**

it is possible?

---

UPDATE:

I have this code:

```
function prefix_movie_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'test/([^/]+)', 'index.php?test=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'prefix_movie_rewrite_rule' );


function prefix_register_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'test';

    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'prefix_register_query_var' );
```

Now:

how do I open the wordpress post page with data of my table?

Comment: You don't need to create a table for that, you can use a custom post type : https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types

Comment: I already have thousands of data in the table...

Comment: The ..../data1 part of the url is a primary key or some unique value on your custom table? I'm not sure what you want to do.

Comment: Yes: the ..../data1 part of the url is a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform cusom SQL queries on the Wordpress database using [WPDB](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

For example:

```
$row = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->test WHERE id = 123");
```

You can then access your id, name and description fields like so:

```
echo $row['id'];
echo $row['name'];
echo $row['description'];
```